# PHP - Get raw image data from image in a HTML document

Tags: php, html, image, mime-types, binary-data

How do i properly grab an image that is displayed in a HTML document and feed it to PHP to be read as image binary. I do not have direct access to the image file. The image i am trying to grab is fed to the client with HTML via PHP and printed in HTML format and using an `<img>` tag to display the image. The src is just a link to the same page i am currently on. The link is a GET request.

The link looks like this:

```
GETIMAGE.php?type=small&path=/path/to/image.png
```

This does not return the actual image with image MIME types. But rather a HTML displaying the image.

I do not have access to the source code in GETIMAGE.php file. This is encrypted as i am using a portal solution that is licensed.

This is the source that is returned from the GETIMAGE.php script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>GETIMAGE.php (80×112)</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://portal.craftnordic.com/PORTAL/GETIMAGE.php?type=small&amp;path=Path/To/Image.png">
</body>
```

Comment: post your GETIMAGE.php script

Comment: @Lee I do not have access to the GETIMAGE.php code. It is encrypted as it is part of a licensed application called Xinet WebNative Portal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: In which case, can you post a "view source" of the GETIMAGE.php script so we know exactly what data your working with. I have a feeling the GETIMAGE script has a referrer check on it, that will only output the raw image data if the script is called from itself (based on your comments to previous answers)

Comment: @Lee Added the source that is returned from the GETIMAGE.php file.

Comment: Ok the only thing i can think of is to use the curl library in php and set the `CURLOPT_REFERER` option to the same as the image url and see what comes back. I can't really help you any further than that without a working link i can debug myself, as its a fairly specific problem to the xinet protal rather than a general programming thing.

Comment: @Lee using `cURL` gave me positive results. But i was not able to use it properly. It gets an image with image/jpeg MIME and all in the header. But it includes more than just the image. It has headers such as `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. I have moved from `cURL` to `fsockopen` because i needed to have authentication in it. I could not figure out how to do authentication with `cURL`. I have opened a new question for more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834971/php-get-image-with-fsockopen/19835074?noredirect=1#comment29494924_19835074)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your script, it is hard to figure out what you are looking for. Let's assume the page generates output like this:

```
<img src="http://imgplacewhatever.com/lskjdflksdjf.png" />
```

Using this excellent [DOM Parsing Library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), we can do something like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('GETIMAGE.php?type=small&path=/path/to/image.png');
$pictures = array();
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
   $pictures[] = $element->src;
}

foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
   $data = file_get_contents($picture);
   ## Do something with the data.
}
```

Then you will have an array of all pictures in `$pictures`.

Good luck.

Comment: I have also tried this. This will return the links of all images in the HTML. The link is just the same link as i am reading the HTML document from. This will not give me raw image data. (which is what i need)

Comment: You can use `file_get_contents` to get the stream. The answer was updated.

Comment: This will not work (already tried). It reads in the HTML that the image is displayed on and not the raw image data.

Comment: I understand. If you use the DOM parser and get the absolute URLs of the image, you can use `file_get_contents()` to get the data stream.

Comment: I have already tried the DOM parser library. It didn't get me anywhere. There is no direct link to the images, only a PHP script that prints them out in a HTML document. The images them self are stored in a safe folder on a different server. I work on 2 servers. One is the data server that holds all the data, and the other displays it to the user. I am currently on the server that displays data.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Please post a truncated version of the HTML page you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_get_contents() method to get the data.

Here you can use

```
$filePath=$_GET['path'];
$imageData=file_get_contents($filePath);
```

Comment: I have already tried this method. This will read the HTML document the image is displayed on, and not the raw image data. I need it to be raw image data.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you for example if i use $imageData=file_get_contents('https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png'); then that will load the google logo icon binary data to $imageData

Comment: Try to specify the exact path of image like this

Comment: I do not have exact images path, and nor do i have direct access to it. It is running on a data server that transfers the content to the other server that grabs the data from the data server and sends it to a client.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you ever found an answer, but I finally did. The data that was being received by file_get_contents - or any CURL method - was actually returning data in a gzip format. When I saved the output to a file and extracted it as a gzip archive, the image was there.